# (discord.js)if I type` >clear 1` it clears 100 messages instead of 1 and if I type `>c @user 1` it works and clears only 1 message

Tags: javascript, command, discord, discord.js

Im trying to make a clear command (discord.js)and if I type `>clear 1` it clears 100 messages instead and if I type `>c @user 1` it works and clears only 1 message

```
module.exports = {
  commands: 'clear',
  permissionError: "you can't use that! :CattoBONK:",
  callback: (message, arguments, text) => {

    const user = message.mentions.users.first();
    // Parse Amount
    const amount = !!parseInt(message.content.split(' ')[1]) ? parseInt(message.content.split(' ')[1]) : parseInt(message.content.split(' ')[2])
    if (!amount) return message.reply('Must specify an amount to delete!');
    if (!amount && !user) return message.reply('Must specify a user and amount, or just an amount, of messages to purge!');
    // Fetch 100 messages (will be filtered and lowered up to max amount requested)
    message.channel.messages.fetch({
     limit: 100,
    }).then((messages) => {
      if (user) {
        const filterBy = user ? user.id : Client.user.id;
        messages = messages.filter(m => m.author.id === filterBy).array().slice(0, amount);
      }
      deleteAmount = parseInt(arguments[0]);
      message.channel.bulkDelete(deleteAmount + 1, true).catch(error => console.log(error.stack));
      message.channel.bulkDelete(messages).catch(error => console.log(error.stack));
    });
  },
  permissions: 'MANAGE_MESSAGES',
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Problem**

Well, the issue here should be relatively simple to find, given that the only difference between the command working and not working is whether or not a user mention is present. So let's look at what happens in your code when `user` (the first mention in the message) is undefined:

```
// Fetch 100 messages (will be filtered and lowered up to max amount requested)
message.channel.messages.fetch({
 limit: 100,
}).then((messages) => {
  if (user) {
    const filterBy = user ? user.id : Client.user.id;
    messages = messages.filter(m => m.author.id === filterBy).array().slice(0, amount);
  }
  deleteAmount = parseInt(arguments[0]);
  message.channel.bulkDelete(deleteAmount + 1, true).catch(error => console.log(error.stack));
  message.channel.bulkDelete(messages).catch(error => console.log(error.stack));
});
```

In this code, if the user is defined, `messages` is filtered by all messages sent by the user, and then furthered sliced such that no more than `amount` messages will be deleted. But if the user is undefined, `messages` *is not filtered whatsoever*, meaning all 100 messages that were fetched are going to be deleted.

**The Solution**

So here's an example of a potential (untested) fix:

```
// Fetch 100 messages (will be filtered and lowered up to max amount requested)
message.channel.messages.fetch({
 limit: 100,
}).then((messages) => {
  if (user) {
    //User is defined (one mention)
    const filterBy = user ? user.id : Client.user.id;
    messages = messages.filter(m => m.author.id === filterBy).array().slice(0, amount);
  }
  else {
    //User is undefined (no mention)
    messages = messages.array().slice(0, amount);
  }

  message.channel.bulkDelete(messages).catch(error => console.log(error.stack));
});
```

So now we *are* filtering the messages to limit them by `amount` when there is no user mention in the message.

Comment: THANK YOU, it works perfectly fine, I have been searching for a solution for days now, thank you very much :D

Comment: No problem!! ;)